# Current_page? is not defined in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two views `quotation.html.erb` and `calculate.html.erb`. I have `quotation.html.erb` set up correctly. Data will be retrieved from `tints` entity when the drop down menu is chosen correctly from the form in `quotation.html.erb`. It will then generate a quotation by rendering a view, `generate.html.erb`

This is what I have for my `tints_controller.rb`

```
def calculator
  render 'calculator'
end

def quotation
  render 'quotation'
end

def generate
  // a lot of formulas here
  // @measurements will get the measurement from tint entity
    if current_page?(:controller => 'tints', :action => 'quotation') //this is my question
      @measurements_front = @measurements.front
      @measurements_side = @measurements.side
      @measurements_rear = @measurements.rear
      @measurements_roof = @measurements.roof
    else
      @measurements_front = params[:front]
      @measurements_side = params[:side]
      @measurements_rear = params[:rear]
      @measurements_roof = params[:roof]
    end
end
```

Now I am trying to create a page, `calculate.html.erb`, for users to input value in the `text_field` instead of selecting from the available data from the drop down menu. User will input values (as in integer) manually (front, side, rear, roof) and submit the form to get quotation from the view `generate.html.erb`

So here is my question. I am trying to use `current_page?` helper to see what page the user is in. If the user is in `quotation.html.erb`, it will get the `@measurements` from the table. If the user is in `calculate.html.erb`, it will get the `:front, :side, :rear: roof`.

I tried several methods and I still get the error `undefined method`current_page?'`. Does`current_page?` still exists in Rails 5 or we have to define it by ourselves?

Also, I have my `routes.rb` set up as below.

```
//More routes here
get '/quotation/tints' => 'tints#quotation', :as => 'tints_quotation'
get '/calculator/tints' => 'tints#calculator', :as => 'tints_calculator'
post '/quotation/tints/generate' => 'tints#generate', :as => 'generate_tints_quotation'
post '/calculator/tints/generate' => 'tints#generate', :as => 'generate_tints_calculator'
```

Answer (score 2):

[`current_page?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) still exists in Ruby on Rails 5.

But it is a view helper method and therefore not available in the context of a controller.